# Unhashable numpy ndarray with vectorize function

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization, numpy-ndarray

I have a dataframe with a column containing numpy ndarrays

```
print(COM_DETAIL['COM_CLOSESTID'])
```

[image]

I then have a dictionary

```
COM_DICT = dict(zip(COM_DETAIL1.index,COM_DETAIL1['COM_CODE']))
print(COM_DICT)
```

[image]

I try to replace the value of COM_CLOSESTID with the result of the dictionary with vectorize function:

```
COM_DETAIL['COM_CLOSEST'] = n.vectorize(COM_DICT.get)(COM_DETAIL['COM_CLOSESTID'])
```

But I got an error :-/

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [118], in <cell line: 62>()
     57         COM_DETAIL = p.read_excel(s)
     59     return COM_DETAIL,DEP_DETAIL,REG_DETAIL
---> 62 COM_DETAIL, DEP_DETAIL, REG_DETAIL = territoire(init= 0)

Input In [118], in territoire(init)
     41 print(COM_DETAIL['COM_CLOSESTID'])
     42 print(COM_DICT)
---> 43 COM_DETAIL['COM_CLOSEST'] = n.vectorize(COM_DICT.get)(COM_DETAIL['COM_CLOSESTID'])
     44 COM_DETAIL = COM_DETAIL.drop('COM_CLOSESTID', axis=1)
     46 s = path_output_territoires+'\COM_DETAIL.xlsx'

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py:2163, in vectorize.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2160     vargs = [args[_i] for _i in inds]
   2161     vargs.extend([kwargs[_n] for _n in names])
-> 2163 return self._vectorize_call(func=func, args=vargs)

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py:2241, in vectorize._vectorize_call(self, func, args)
   2239     res = func()
   2240 else:
-> 2241     ufunc, otypes = self._get_ufunc_and_otypes(func=func, args=args)
   2243     # Convert args to object arrays first
   2244     inputs = [asanyarray(a, dtype=object) for a in args]

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py:2201, in vectorize._get_ufunc_and_otypes(self, func, args)
   2197     raise ValueError('cannot call `vectorize` on size 0 inputs '
   2198                      'unless `otypes` is set')
   2200 inputs = [arg.flat[0] for arg in args]
-> 2201 outputs = func(*inputs)
   2203 # Performance note: profiling indicates that -- for simple
   2204 # functions at least -- this wrapping can almost double the
   2205 # execution time.
   2206 # Hence we make it optional.
   2207 if self.cache:

TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

Can someone help me with it? Thanks

Comment: Why are you trying to use `np.vectorize`?  It isn't a performance tool.

Comment: Dict `get` expects a valid dict key like a string or number, not a list or array.  Your column, a Series, is object dtype with list or array elements.  `np.vectorize` will pass those cells, one at a time to the function.  It is not going to iterate over the elements of those arrays.  As I said, `np.vectorize` is not a performance tool, and can give errors if you don't understand what it's doing.  The error occurs when if tries to determine the dtype of the return.  `otypes` can be used to skip that step, but may not help here.

Comment: @hpaulj I am not very familiar with vectorize true, but I though it would help in this case. How would you do to replace efficiently values with the ones of the dictionary?

Comment: I'm not sure this anything more efficient.  `dict` has to be called one key at a time.

Comment: Quoting from the docs: "The `vectorize` function is provided primarily for convenience, not for
performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop."